# how to update the vendor folder for https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform.git for terraform

Tags: go, dependency-management, terraform, godeps

Hi i am following steps given for hashicorp/terraform and performed below activity

```
# Get latest master branch's dependencies staged in local $GOPATH
git checkout master
git pull
godep restore -v

# Make your way to the dependency in question and checkout the target ref
pushd $GOPATH/src/github.com/some/dependency
git checkout [latest]

# Head back to Terraform on a feature branch and update the dependncy to the
# version currently in your $GOPATH
popd
git checkout my-feature-branch
godep update github.com/...
```

after this i can see my Godep.json file has been updated however i dont see changes in the vendor folder . it still points to old. Well i am looking emr support from vendor for that i am updating go-aws-sdk which is available with the latest go-aws-sdk. when i called go update github.com/... it has modified the godep.json but not vendor folder .
Could somebody please let me know the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a `godep restore -v` again. `update` only updates the dependency in the `Godep.json` file.